# Could not boot to Ubuntu after software update, Grub2 corrupted

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have a dual boot on Dell XPS with Windows and Ubuntu 20.04, it was working fine until I installed KDE desktop. Since then I'm having boot issues.

First time it happened I was able to fix it using boot-repair live CD.
This happened again after a software update, boot-repair could not fix the issue.
This is the log generated by boot-repair http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/vKDSynyVw5/
Is there a way to fix this.

I'm able to boot to Windows from Grub menu but not to Ubuntu. I tried changing to `nomodeset` but it didn't help.

Comment: You have UEFI system. Make sure you do not turn on or try to boot in BIOS mode as you somehow installed a BIOS boot grub to gpt's protective MBR. That will not boot. Issue sounds more like Windows did an update & turned its fast start up back on and/or did a UEFI update & that reset some UEFI settings. Check UEFI settings & fast start up in Windows. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: When I installed Ubuntu, I turned off fast boot, and I have only sleep and lock in shutdown settings.

Comment: Windows turns fast start up back on with updates. Fast boot is an UEFI setting that when making changes, should also be off.

Comment: What I meant was, fast boot option is still turned off at the moment, since it was tuned.

Comment: Are you able to boot recovery mode, second entry in grub? It also looks like you have Intel RST still on. That often causes issues.

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. What version is it?

Comment: @oldfred In BIOS raid is not turned on. I could not boot into any entry. I used `set debug=all` it is getting stuck loading initrd image, `command/verifiers.c:88: file /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-40-generic type:131076`
@David I have Ubuntu 20.04, update description.
Even `ls -l (hd1,gpt6)/boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-40-generic type:131076` on Grub menu hangs

Comment: Not familar with kernel errors. Does older kernel also give same error?

Comment: At this point I don't know what really happened, `command/verifiers.c:88` is from Grub. At the moment I'm trying to install Grub again from live CD.

Comment: Finally understood what happened. Boot-repair was done in legacy boot mode but my system is set up to use UEFI. Able to fix this by booting boot-repair usb in UEFI mode and then running the commands.